# How to do a "Zoom to me" function to filter/scroll down on a list in flutter for a leaderboard?

Tags: list, flutter, dart, filter, scroll

I'm trying to make a **leaderboard** for a list of users and as a quick way for the current user to find what his rank is I made a button which should **filter/scroll** down in the list and get the first **5 users** that are **ahead/onTop** of the current user and then the **4** other users that **rank behind** him in the list while the current user should be in the middle.

I tried to play around with lists and tried to filter them but I don't have much to show I found this 2 links [here](https://flutterbyexample.com/lesson/filtering-elements-where-take-while-and-skip-while) and [here](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/lists/long-lists) and got some ideas from them this is what I got so far:

My lists:

```
bool _isZoomed = false;
List<int> items = [
    0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20,
  ];
List<int> _filteredItems = [];
```

My function:

```
zoomOnMe() {
    List<int> _users = [];
    _users.addAll(items);
    _users.retainWhere(
      (user) {
        var _zoom = items.takeWhile((i) => i <= 5);
        _isZoomed = true;
        return _zoom.contains(user);
      },
    );
    setState(() {
      _filteredItems = _users;
    });
  }
```

My widgets:

```
            TextButton(
              onPressed: zoomOnMeBiach,
              child: const Text('Zoom on me biach'),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: ListView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemCount:
                    _isSearching == true ? _filteredItems.length : items.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return ListTile(
                    title: Text(
                      _isSearching == true
                          ? _filteredItems[index].toString()
                          : items[index].toString(),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
```

What I got:

[image]

What I want:

[image]

Comment: You want the 4 ahead and the 4 behind so there are no sort to do in list why you don't simply scrollTo the current user rank

Comment: thank you for the comment but I found a solution for this I just used https://pub.dev/packages/scrollable_positioned_list